# Entity framework , many changes missing after applying all migrations successfully,

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

`get-migrations` shows full list of all my migrations but only half of them is in the _MigrationHistory and the database has changes from these half of them. No errors , all migrations applied successfully.

> issue comes while applying migrations having int to float changes were i had to manually add 
>   `Sql("ALTER TABLE xxx DROP CONSTRAINT DF__TBL_OPRTN__OPRTN__6497E884");` .

**Is there any possible reason for these kind of behaviour from ef , any way to debug this?**

thanks

Comment: Generate a script and see why the missing ones didn't get applied: `update-database -Script -SourceMigration $InitialDatabase`

Comment: but i tried -verbose , they were okay.

Comment: @SteveGreene i tried `update-database -Script -SourceMigration $InitialDatabase` , but script upto last migration is there but only half of them is really applied.

Comment: There should be a block of code for each migration that 1) checks __MigrationHistory if it has been applied, 2) If not applied, runs the migration code, 3) Inserts record into __MigrationHistory to denote it has been applied. So find one that has not been applied and see why or run it in SQL Server Managment Studio.