# Entity Framework sometimes doesn't recognize past migrations after DB restore

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Recently, I've started to experience an issue with EF.

Intermittently, I will copy a DB and restore it for testing, and EF will fail to recognize many of the previous migrations.

`Get-Migrations` will return a list of half or so of the applied migrations. If I check the `_MigrationHistory` table in the restored DB, I will find every migration that I expect to see in the table.

If I try to execute `Update-Database`, EF will try to start applying all migrations from the point where `Get-Migrations` leaves off, until the last migration is applied. Because all of these migrations have already actually been applied; this fails because the migrations don't match the current scheme of the DB anymore.

What's going on? Has anyone experienced this before? What can I do to make EF recognize all the other applied migrations? Removing all the past migrations and creating a new initial migration isn't an option. I need to try and fix the state of EF.

Note: this doesn't always happen, it appears to happen intermittently, after a DB restore. Sometimes dropping the restored DB and trying again manages to fix it. This hasn't happened in Production yet but I'm concerned it will.

I've tried doing some googling on this issue but all I seem to find are people asking how to migrate or how to reset migrations. I'm looking for a way to fix EF's state so it recognizes all the Migrations found in `_MigrationHistory`. Thanks for your time!

Comment: One way that can happen is if you changed some name spaces. Are all the context  keys the same in __MigrationHistory? To troubleshoot script out the migration and see what EF is checking against.

Comment: @SteveGreene yes, they are. 

Another interesting observation: If I change my connection string back to the original DB that I copied from, `Get-Migrations` returns all of the applied migrations I expect to see. Both copies of the DB have matching `_MigrationHistory` tables. No namespace changes have been made.

Comment: Try doing a `update-database -SourceMigration $InitialDatabase -Script` and look at the if checks on __MigrationHistory to see why EF is trying to re-apply them.

Comment: So this is weird - I did what you suggested, and when I run the query the script outputs to find the latest migration, it's returning the last migration that I expect to see (a migration from 2018), but when I execute `get-migrations`, it doesn't show any migrations past 2014. 
I figured out what Migration EF thinks is the "next pending", it is a migration from 2014. If I grab the @currentMigration and then execute this: 
`IF @CurrentMigration < '201407191910114_Added custom Data Migration Functions'
SELECT 'true';` , "true" is not selected because the expression evaluates to false

Comment: So the script that it generated seems to be grabbing the correct `@currentMigration`, and it seems to be able to recognize that the current migration is > than the 2014 migration... however this doesn't correlate at all with how the command line `get-migrations` and `update-database` are behaving. Really at a loss here. 

P.S. @SteveGreene, I recognized your user name from another post I'm following. Short story: thanks for helping out the community! other post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44229182/entity-framework-many-changes-missing-after-applying-all-migrations-successful

Comment: Yeah, I've fought many EF battles :) It can be quirky. Another thing I do is explicity add the parameters -ProjectName, -StartupProjectName and -ConnectioinStringName because relying on the conventions is flakey. Also, when we get to certain milestones we will "roll up" old migrations as Chris describes [here](https://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/).

Comment: Thanks for all the help @SteveGreene!! It turned out to be user error... I went ahead and answered my own question if you're curious what happened. Thanks again for your assistance!

Answer (score 3):

So... ultimately this was user error, but the problem was very strange so I'll answer my own question to help others in the future. Short story: trust EF to do the right thing. You probably messed something up.

Basically what I found out is I wasn't connecting to the database that I thought I was connecting to. I had a typo in my connection string, and this caused EF to create a new DB and partially perform all of our ancient, 4 year old migrations. It would fail part-way through because one of these old migrations referenced files that aren't a part of the solution anymore.

Sequence of events:

1. Opened Sql Studio Management Studio (SSMS)
2. ran a TSQL script to copy the database with a new name

   - (note: at this time, there are 2 databases now in my SSMS, the original and the copy)
3. Change the connection string in my project to the new database

   - (note: this is where I introduced a typo in the connection string)
4. Ran the program - started getting "model has changed, please run update-database" error messages.
5. Ran `get-migrations -verbose`, which only returned some of the applied migrations and the connection string it outputted *looked* right to me.
6. Checked the new DB in SSMS and found it was full of data and had all migrations applied

   - (note: SSMS still only showed 2 Dbs)

It was about this time that I came here and started posting. @SteveGreene suggested I try generating the SQL script... I did and copied it into SSMS on the new db and found it was able to find the latest migrations... but this didn't correlate with how `get-migrations` was behaving.

This is when I refreshed my SSMS object explorer. That's when the 3rd DB suddenly appeared, and I figured out that it was created when I introduced a typo in my connection string. The project is configured to run migrations automatically, so this caused a 3rd db to get created and execute all of the old migrations... one of which referenced a file that isn't in the solution anymore and failed. I checked the third DB and it had no data and only some of the migrations applied.

All I had to do was delete the extra DB and fix the typo in my connection string... [image: facepalm]